# What are function typedefs / function-type aliases in Dart?

Tags: typedef, dart

I have read the description, and I understand that it is a function-type alias.

- A typedef, or function-type alias, gives a function type a name that you can use when declaring fields and return types. A typedef retains type information when a function type is assigned to a variable.
- http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#kix.yyd520hand9j

But how do I use it? Why declaring fields with a function-type? When do I use it? What problem does it solve?

I think I need one or two real code examples.

Comment: Note that this question is strictly related to **function** typedefs. In Dart 2.13, a new feature was added that supports *generalized* type aliases for all types. 
I created a new questions for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66847006/6509751.

All answers here (and the question) only discuss the legacy format, which is why that was necessary.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

A common usage pattern of typedef in Dart is defining a callback interface. For example:

```dart
typedef void LoggerOutputFunction(String msg);

class Logger {
  LoggerOutputFunction out;
  Logger() {
    out = print;
  }
  void log(String msg) {
    out(msg);
  }
}

void timestampLoggerOutputFunction(String msg) {
  String timeStamp = new Date.now().toString();
  print('${timeStamp}: $msg');
}

void main() {
  Logger l = new Logger();
  l.log('Hello World');
  l.out = timestampLoggerOutputFunction;
  l.log('Hello World');
}
```

Running the above sample yields the following output:

> Hello World
>   2012-09-22 10:19:15.139: Hello World

The typedef line says that LoggerOutputFunction takes a String parameter and returns void.

timestampLoggerOutputFunction matches that definition and thus can be assigned to the out field.

Let me know if you need another example.

Comment: looks good. You have any good example where return type string is?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `new DateTime.now().toString()` ?

Comment: Note; this answer uses the legacy `typedef` notation. The preferred one is `typedef LoggerOutputFunction = void Function(String msg);` (from https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-use-the-legacy-typedef-syntax)

Comment: please give me another example @Cutch

Comment: Is typedef used to give another name to just callback interface? Or it works with any types. I tried something like `typedef currency double`. Error : '
Typedefs must have an explicit list of parameters.'

Comment: Don't forget that in Dart everything is an Object, even functions (methods). That means you can assign a function to a variable. This may be surprising to Java users.

Comment: @BangOperator currently typedefs supports only function types, there is an open issue for supporting non-function types, like your example using double. https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65

Comment: Now, Dart (starting with Dart 2.13) also supports generalized typedefs for non-function types. See the following answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66847007/6509751

Answer (score 33):

Dart 1.24 introduces a new typedef syntax to also support generic functions. The previous syntax is still supported.

```
typedef F = List<T> Function<T>(T);
```

For more details see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generic-function-type-alias.md

Function types can also be specified inline

```
void foo<T, S>(T Function(int, S) aFunction) {...}
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs

Answer (score 30):

```
typedef LoggerOutputFunction = void Function(String msg);
```

this looks much more clear than previous version

Answer (score 11):

Just slightly modified answer, according to the latest typedef syntax, The example could be updated to:

```
typedef LoggerOutputFunction = void Function(String msg);

class Logger {
  LoggerOutputFunction out;
  Logger() {
    out = print;
  }
  void log(String msg) {
    out(msg);
  }
}

void timestampLoggerOutputFunction(String msg) {
  String timeStamp = new Date.now().toString();
  print('${timeStamp}: $msg');
}

void main() {
  Logger l = new Logger();
  l.log('Hello World');
  l.out = timestampLoggerOutputFunction;
  l.log('Hello World');
}
```

Comment: May you say why you assigned `print` to `out`? what is the `print`?

Comment: `print` is Dart's print function, so in the default constructor will assign print method to out which means if we didn't supply the func, it will use the default print one which comes from Dart.
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/print.html

Answer (score 7):

`Typedef` in Dart is used to create a user-defined function (alias) for other application functions,

```
Syntax: typedef function_name (parameters);
```

With the help of a typedef, we can also assign a variable to a function.

```
Syntax:typedef variable_name = function_name;
```

After assigning the variable, if we have to invoke it then we go as:

```
Syntax: variable_name(parameters);
```

**Example:**

```
// Defining alias name
typedef MainFunction(int a, int b);

functionOne(int a, int b) {
  print("This is FunctionOne");
  print("$a and $b are lucky numbers !!");
}

functionTwo(int a, int b) {
  print("This is FunctionTwo");
  print("$a + $b is equal to ${a + b}.");
}

// Main Function
void main() {
  // use alias
  MainFunction number = functionOne;

  number(1, 2);

  number = functionTwo;
 // Calling number
  number(3, 4);
}
```

**Output:**

```
This is FunctionOne
1 and 2 are lucky numbers !!
This is FunctionTwo
3 + 4 is equal to 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Since dart version 2.13 you can use `typedef` not only with functions but with every object you want.

Eg this code is now perfectly valid:

```
typedef IntList = List<int>;
IntList il = [1, 2, 3];
```

For more details see updated info:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs

Comment: Oh wow, gamechanger. The lack of typedefs for non-functions was my only gripe about dart.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_typedef.htm

```
 typedef ManyOperation(int firstNo , int secondNo);   //function signature 
    Add(int firstNo,int second){ 
       print("Add result is ${firstNo+second}"); 
    }  
    Subtract(int firstNo,int second){
       print("Subtract result is ${firstNo-second}"); 
    }  
    Divide(int firstNo,int second){ 
       print("Divide result is ${firstNo/second}"); 
    }  
    Calculator(int a,int b ,ManyOperation oper){ 
       print("Inside calculator"); 
       oper(a,b); 
    }  
    main(){ 
       Calculator(5,5,Add); 
       Calculator(5,5,Subtract); 
       Calculator(5,5,Divide); 
    }
```