# How to write a function type in Dart

Tags: dart

This seems like a very obvious question to me, but I cannot seem to find the answer.

How do I write a function type in Dart.

I can use some canned forms like `ValueChanged<T>` or `ValueSetter<T>`, but how are they defined?  How can I write general function types like `T -> U -> V`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545762/what-is-a-typedef-in-dart

Comment: Thanks for making the duplicate, I never would have expected it to be bolted into typedefs.

I am assuming then there is no way to express an unnamed function type without using a typedef?

Comment: There is syntax without typedefs. See https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs

Answer (score -3):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you are referring to Generic Types. These types are used by functions when you are not sure which type your function is going to use in order to avoid code duplication. For example, let's say you have a class with a method that stores numbers in a List:

```
class StoreInt {
  storeInList(int value);
}
```

But later, you decide you now want it to store Strings, so you create another class:

```
class StoreString {
   storeInList(String value);
 }
```

Generics allow you to write this class once and use it to store any kind of object you want:

```
class Store<T> {
  storeInList(T value);
}
```

As far as I know, you don't create generics in dart, you just specify a single letter in between diamond operators as shown in the previous example.

You can find more information on generics here: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Comment: No, generics is not what I am asking about, I am asking about how to type functions.