# How can I extend functions in Dart?

Tags: dart

I know about [the `extension` feature in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751), but how can I use it with functions?

Essentially, I am facing two problems:

1. What do I extend **on** (`extension FancyFunction on ?`)?
   I would want to add a function like `toAsync` that makes the function return a `Future` of its usual result.
2. How would I implement **calling**?
   I could create a `callAsync` member that executes `this()` or `this.call()`, but I would like to use regular calling syntax, i.e. just parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What do I extend on when extending functions?

Dart has a [`Function` type](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Function-class.html). This can be extended on and you can pass type parameters if you want.
Here is an [example from the changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/36e4d5e3c206822246dc525498c4b011f4755f6c/CHANGELOG.md#language):

```dart
extension CurryFunction<R, S, T> on R Function(S, T) { ... }
```

Furthermore, you can extend any [`typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12545762/6509751) of a function.

For adding the `toAsync` and `callAsync` functionality a generic return type `R` will do. Note that this will only extend functions without parameters as `Function()` takes no parameters:

```dart
extension FancyFunction<R> on R Function() {
  Future<R> Function() toAsync() => () async => this();
}
```

Now, this could be used like this:

```dart
void syncHello() => print('Hello');

void main() {
  final asyncHello = syncHello.toAsync();

  asyncHello().then((_) => print(', World!'));
}
```

### How do I implement calling?

Every class in Dart can [implement the `call` method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes). You can either execute this method simply using **parentheses** or with `.call()`.
Here is an example implementation:

```dart
extension FancyFunction<R> on R Function() {
  Future<R> call() async => this();
}
```

Since every `Function` already implements `call`, the extension member cannot be called *implicitly*.
Instead, you will have to **explicitly** declare your function as a `FancyFunction` to be able to call it:

```dart
void syncHello() => print('Hello');

void main() {
  FancyFunction(syncHello)()
      .then((_) => print(', World!'));
}
```

Note that `FancyFunction(syncHello)()` is the same method call as `FancyFunction(syncHello).call()`.

However, now we have two problems:

- We have to *explicitly declare* our function to be a `FancyFunction`, which somewhat defeats the purpose of having an extension.
- The `call` method will always return a `Future` as the regular call method cannot be accessed anymore when we declare a `FancyFunction`.

Instead, adding a method like `callAsync` seems like a better solution:

```dart
extension FancyFunction<R> on R Function() {
  Future<R> callAsync() async => this();
}
```

Now, `callAsync` can be used implicitly again:

```dart
void syncHello() => print('Hello');

void main() {
  syncHello.callAsync()
      .then((_) => print(', World!'));

  syncHello(); // regular call
}
```