# How to make the function type safe?

Tags: dart

I am pretty new in Dart and I would like to know, how to make Function defined as a property more type safe:

```
class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {

  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  final Function addNewTx;

  NewTransaction(this.addNewTx);
```

With type safety I mean, that I can determine what are the inputs and outputs. Now I can pass anything to **Function** object.

Comment: Already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545762/what-is-a-typedef-in-dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When declaring a `Function` parameter, declare the return type and parameters.

In your example, I will imagine a `void` return type, and a `String` parameter.  As a result:

```
class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  final void Function(String) addNewTx;

  NewTransaction(this.addNewTx);

}
```